# Area of a segment

Tags: circles, area

Two circles of radii 5cm and 12cm are drawn, partly overlapping as shown. Their centres are 13cm apart. Find the area common to the circles?

[image]

Comment: Show us the work you have done, please. It can be done with calculus, but it is probable that your answer must not have integrals.

Comment: Hint 1: If in a ordinary triangle with sides $a,b,c$ we have that $a^2=b^2+c^2$ then this triangle is...

Comment: Hint 2: You can assume the area as sets, where $n(A\cup B)=n(A)+n(B)-n(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Draw a vertical line where the two legs of the triangle meet. Then solve for the partial area of the sector by subtracting the area of the triangle from the area of the sector.

Answer (score 1):

We can split the area into two sectors minus the equaliteral triangles formed inside their sectors.

In math terms:

So we must first find the angles inside the right triangle:

$$\theta = \sin^{-1}(\frac{12}{13})$$

$$\theta = 67.4\  \text{degrees}$$

Similarly we can find the other angles:

$$67.4 + 90 + x = 180$$

$$x = 22.6\ \text{degrees}$$

Now, we can use the sectors:

$$22.6*2 = 45.2$$
$$144\pi*\frac{45.2}{360} = 56.8$$
Now, we have to subtract the triangle to get the remaining area:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}*12*12*\sin(45.2) = 51.1$$
Area that remains:
$$56.8 - 51.1 = 5.7$$

Now we do the other triangle:
$$25\pi*\frac{134.8}{360} = 29.4$$

Area of triangle:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}*5*5*\sin(134.8) = 8.9$$

Subtracting:
$$20.5$$

Adding that to our other area:

Our final answer becomes:
$$20.5 + 5.7 = 26.2$$

Comment if you have any questions. This was a lot to take in.

Comment: @DiegoMath what do you suggest is an easier way then?

Comment: Look the Vishwa Iyer's answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I did....

Comment: @DiegoMath He did do exactly that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize now.

Comment: Thank you so much I fully understand it now. Weird how drawing the initial line makes the question so much simpler!